# JPA: Problem with persisting Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence, foreign-keys, orm

I got two Entity:

Customer Entity

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Facility> facilities;

//Setter and Getter for name and facilities

public void addFacility(Facility facility){
    this.facilities.add(facility);
}
}
```

Facility Entity

```
@Entity
public class Facility {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_FK")
private Customer customer;

private String name;

//Setter and Getter, equals and hashcode
...
}
```

So in my main I do this

```
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("Wake Forest University");
    Facility facility = new Facility();
    facility.setName("Tom Cruise");
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EntityClassPU").createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    customer.addFacility(facility);
    entityManager.persist(customer);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

`Wake Forest University` is successfully insert into `Customer`, and `Tom Cruise` is successfully insert in `Facility`, however inside `Facility`, the `CUSTOMER_FK` value is null, which suggest that I fail persist the foreign key contraint. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your relation between `Customer` and `Facility` is a bi-directional association, you **must** manage both sides of the association. You can do this manually but I suggest doing it in the `addFacility()` method:

```
public void addFacility(Facility facility){
    if (this.facilities == null) { 
        this.facilities = new ArrayList<Facility>();
    } 
    this.facilities.add(facility);
    facility.setCustomer(this); // that's the part you're currently missing
}
```

Comment: @PascalThivent : can you kindly spare few minutes to help me with this problem >> http://stackoverflow.com/q/24280099/1210813